# Jumbotron not centering properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm using jumbotron in the latest Bootstrap 4.5.2, and I put a `<p>` tag inside 3 columns and make it center. But after that, I noticed the space on the right of the last column (the third one) is less than the space of the first column (the left side of it) which means it is not fully centered. I tried to use `padding` but it still looks the same.

```css
.jumbotron {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p>
          Gravida dis placerat lectus ante vel nunc euismod est turpis sodales. Diam tempor dui lacinia accumsan vivamus. Gravida dis placerat lectus ante vel nunc euismod est turpis sodales. Diam tempor dui lacinia accumsan vivamus.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <p>
          Gravida dis placerat lectus ante vel nunc euismod est turpis sodales. Diam tempor dui lacinia accumsan vivamus. Gravida dis placerat lectus ante vel nunc euismod est turpis sodales. Diam tempor dui lacinia accumsan vivamus.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <p>
          Gravida dis placerat lectus ante vel nunc euismod est turpis sodales. Diam tempor dui lacinia accumsan vivamus. Gravida dis placerat lectus ante vel nunc euismod est turpis sodales. Diam tempor dui lacinia accumsan vivamus.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything appears fine on my end. Could you maybe add a screenshot of it in your browser?

Comment: it looks fine to me as well. Are you viewing this on IE11 or something? and did you clear your Browser Cache before viewing changes?

Comment: Here you go sir [Chrome](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IW-5epcSNB7nYr0yRp99FTSKek0PVk5K/view?usp=sharing) and [firefox](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aRXsGarPsoeUdtKBg-NOunQIYwZIiMNr/view?usp=sharing) can you see the space on the right of the last column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is nothing wrong and that's how I see it.

[image: Result]

And the full page:

[image]

and here is from the developer tools:

[image: result]

And another result:

[image: result]